# Django allauth - How to know if user is logged in with socialaccount or account?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth

How to know if user is logged with socialaccount or account?
And get this information in the template?

Comment: I found this solution, i don't know if the best solution but its works,
Create a context_processors in socialaccount and do this query:
`if SocialAccount.objects.filter(user_id=request.user).exists():...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the template tag: `get_social_accounts`

As per documentation:

```
{% get_social_accounts user as accounts %}
Then:
    {{accounts.twitter}} -- a list of connected Twitter accounts
    {{accounts.twitter.0}} -- the first Twitter account
    {% if accounts %} -- if there is at least one social account
```

And if the user is not connected with a social account:

```
{% if user.is_anonymous %}Not logged in.{% else %} Logged in.{% endif %}
```